# for each output of a select statement, execute another query

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, left-join

Please consider this question:

A sqlite db with two tables, and I need to take `bookName` from one table and generate count on each of the results in another table.

```sh
$ sqlite3 Sqlite.db "select bookName from books" 
myBook.1
myBook.2
myBook.3
myBook.4
myBook.5
```

Tried subQuery, probably wrongly, with wrong results:

```sql
sqlite> select count(*) from tags where bookName = (select bookName from books);
753
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```sh
$ sqlite3 SSqlite.db "select bookName from books" | while read a ; do  sqlite3 Sqlite.db "select bookName,count(*) from tags where bookName = \"$a\""; done
myBook.1|753
myBook.2|677
myBook.3|573
myBook.4|656
myBook.5|103
```

This must be possible much simpler within SQL, any input is much appreciated!

Comment: You need `...bookName IN (select bookName from books)`. `=` expects exactly one value on the right hand side, where `IN` expects a set of values.

Comment: ```bash
sqlite> select bookName,count(*) from tags where bookName in (select bookName from books);
myBook.5|2762
sqlite> 
``` 
`In` shows just one book, not all of them. `=` shows just the first book, `=` shows just the last book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want results only for the books in the table `tags`, then you should group by `bookName`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter
FROM tags 
GROUP BY bookName;
```

If you want results for all the books in the table `books` then use a `LEFT` join and aggregation:

```
SELECT b.bookName, COUNT(t.bookName) counter
FROM books b LEFT JOIN tags t
ON t.bookName = b.bookName 
GROUP BY b.bookName;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are looking for grouping query... You almost got that right:

```
select bookName, count(*) from tags group by bookName;
```

Depending on your case you might want to join or right join with your other table (`books`).

Check documentation about:

- [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)